# Does NSMutableDictionary keep a strong reference to an object I put in it via 'setValue:forKey:'?

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary, strong-references

According to Apple's documentation, if I add an object to an `NSMutableDictionary` via the `setObject:forKey:` method, the dictionary will keep a strong reference to it.

But what about the `setValue:forKey:` method? The documentation doesn't say anything about the kind of reference to the object added via this method.
Is it the same as the other one? Does the dictionary keep a strong reference to the object added via this method as well?

Comment: Set value for key? On an array? That's not even possible.

Comment: It is, because NSArray is key-value coding compliant.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `NSMutableDictionary`. My mistake. Correcting...

Comment: @wjl yeah, but KVC compliant for keys that exist. Corrected by the OP now anyway :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NSMutableDictionary` (and `NSMutableArray`) keeps strong references to any object added to it, no matter how it is added.

Comment: And the same is true for NSMutableDictionary.

Answer (score 3):

`NSMutableArray` and `NSArray` keep strong references to objects they contain. These objects are either added using the literal constructor `@[myObject, myObject2, ...]`, the initializers of `NSArray`, or the add/insert methods of `NSMutableArray`.

If you're looking for key/value storage like a map, you want to use `NSDictionary`/`NSMutableDictionary` instead. The `setValue:forKey:` method you're talking about is for key-value coding compliance, which is different.

Additionally, `NSDictionary` and `NSMutableDictionary` keep strong references to value objects, and keep copy references to keys (which must comply to the `NSCopying` protocol).

Comment: I meant `NSMutableDictionary` in the question, sorry. I wrote `NSMutableArray` by mistake but I corrected it. But thanks anyway :)